# Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to adapt a code from php 5.6 to php7, so I replaced mysql with mysqli, but I get the following error:
Fatal error: Function name must be a string on line 12

Here is my code:

```
<?php include("day_image/config.php");
$time=time();
$jour=date("z",$time);
$conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $bdd);
$req="select image from chat_du_jour where jour=$jour";
$res = $conn->query($req);
if (@mysqli_num_rows($res)!=0)
{
$row=@mysqli_fetch_row($res);
}
$req_chemin="select chemin from chat_du_jour where jour=$jour";
$res_chemin = $conn($req_chemin);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res_chemin)!=0)
{
$row_chemin=mysqli_fetch_row($res_chemin);
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just a typo (of sorts)? `$conn` is an object:

```
$conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $bdd);
```

But you're using it as a function name here on line 12 (the line the error message points you to):

```
$res_chemin = $conn($req_chemin);
```

I suspect it ought to be more like:

```
$res_chemin = $conn->query($req_chemin);
```

Comment: Many thanks, Adam, I couldn't see it!
Cheers,
Pierre